# How to toggle filter panel programmatically in MUIx Data grid pro

Tags: reactjs, mui-x-data-grid

We want to introduce a shortcut key ( alt + l ) to toggle the filter panel in MUIx Data grid pro.
[image]

MUIX provides hook **useGridApiRef()** which has function **showFilterPanel()** & **hideFilterPanel()**
but they don't have a function to toggle the filter panel,

Is there a way to know if the filter panel is open or close so that i can conditionally call the above functions.

Thank You,